# How can I pass my string to the email intent?

Tags: javascript, java, android, email

```
        @OverrideView view){
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append(textQr = text.getText().toString().trim());
            buffer.append(text2Qr = text2.getText().toString().trim());
            buffer.append(text3Qr = text3.getText().toString().trim());
            String pass = buffer.toString();



            MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
            try{
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(pass, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300,300);
                BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I have already catch all the string using Stringbuffer class. I want to make an email generator. text,text2,text3 are their respective recipient,subject,body. when I generate and send email the texts are not go their respective content. how am I gonna do that?

Comment: You should first make an effort to post a _minimal yet complete and verifiable example_ (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). First of all: Explain clearly **what** you want to do, **how** are you trying, and **what** would you expect.  Second: Include all the sifnificant parts of your class and methods, not just an incomplete excerpt. Third: Put names with semantic meaning instead of `text2`, `text3...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                "mailto", "support@hello.com", null));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello World");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ABC");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```